# Certain settings keep resetting in VS2013 Professional

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-addins

Recently the sections under `Options>Text Editor>C#>Advanced>Editor Help` and `Options>Text Editor>All Languages>General>Statement Completion` have taken on a mind of their own. Various settings have just started disabling themselves. I re-enable them, they re-disable themselves. It's worth noting that I have *never* disabled these settings.

I cannot think of what I could be doing or what could be installed to cause this to happen. I have an installation of Premium on one machine and Professional on another. They both have largely the same add-ons installed (the Premium copy actually has more installed) and I work on the same solutions with both installations, synced between computers via Dropbox. Switching back and forth between installations does not seem to trigger it.

Has anyone else experienced this? Any ideas how to resolve?

Below are screenshots of the settings that change, how they should be (before) and how they end up (after):

#### Before

[image]

#### After

[image]

---

#### Before

[image]

#### After

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Based on this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn135229.aspx) and the fact that Resharper is installed on Premium but not Professional, I'm suspecting that Resharper is changing settings to suit it and they are being synced across machines.